# Aggregating in SAP Business Objects Webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

I think the issue is fairly simple but I can't manage to get to the result.

I would like to aggregate the result for each store, but keeping in the report all the rows, including the Client and Purchase ones:

| Store | Client | Purchase | DesiredColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store1 | Client1 | 20 | 50 |
| Store1 | Client2 | 30 | 50 |
| Store2 | Client3 | 100 | 600 |
| Store2 | Client4 | 500 | 600 |

I tried something along the lines of Sum and ForEach(Store), but it returns the same exact values for "Purchase".

Does someone know if this is possible at all (and without hierarchies, cause I can't work with them)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Give this formula a try...

```
=Sum([Purchase] In([Store]))
```

This will also work...

```
=Sum([Purchase]) In([Store])
```

[image]

I cannot fully explain the difference. If you want to do more research the topic is "Calculation Contexts". This [article](https://michaelwelter.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/removing-the-confusion-from-calculation-contexts/) has been particularly helpful to me.